# Replacing Some Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I want to change the 'S' from the array into 'l'. but it won't work.
Please help me with this one.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $array = array (
        "romeo/echo/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
        "romeo/echo/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
        "romeo/echo/julion/1996s/1965.jpg",
    );
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if($key == "romeo/echo/julion/'.*?'s/'.*?'.jpg") $value="romeo/echo/julion/'.*?'l/'.*?'.jpg";
    }
    print_r($value);
?>
```

Comment: `str_replace` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** You need to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) along with [call by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
  $value = str_replace('s/','l/',$value);
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/981246

***2.*** Or you can directly go to [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
<?php
function strReplace($n)
{
    return(str_replace('s/','l/',$n));
}

$array = array ("romeo/echo/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
                "romeo/echo/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
                "romeo/echo/julion/1996s/1965.jpg",
);
$final_array = array_map("strReplace", $array);
print_r($final_array);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/981225

***3*** Or go with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$array = preg_replace('/(\d{4})(s\/)/', '$1l/', $array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/981245

Comment: i've deleted my answer. so is this okay if i post it (i mean my last answer that i've deleted) to another question?

Comment: @RheyzaVirgiawanD'first  you can ask a new question anytime. But try to clarify your question clearly that what exactly you want and what isn't working? Also, don't forget to post your code effort too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way,

```
$array = array ("romeo/echo/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
                "romeo/echo/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
                "romeo/echo/julion/1996s/1965.jpg",
);


$array = preg_replace("/(s)(?=\/)/", "l", $array);
print '<pre>';
print_r($array);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => romeo/echo/julion/1991l/1992.jpg
    [1] => romeo/echo/julion/1257l/1258.jpg
    [2] => romeo/echo/julion/1996l/1965.jpg
)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/981216

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    "romeo/echo/julion/1991s/1992.jpg",
    "romeo/echo/julion/1257s/1258.jpg",
    "romeo/echo/julion/1996s/1965.jpg",
];

$array = preg_replace('/(\d{4})(s)/', '$1l', $array);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(32) "romeo/echo/julion/1991l/1992.jpg"
    [1] =>
    string(32) "romeo/echo/julion/1257l/1258.jpg"
    [2] =>
    string(32) "romeo/echo/julion/1996l/1965.jpg"
}
```